# angular p-element as root element inside template

Tags: html, angular, custom-element, angular-template

I am trying to follow the Angular's introductory "Tour Of Heroes" tutorial.
In "[Show The Hero Object](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#show-the-hero-object)" section, you are supposed to change the contents of the heroes.component.html template from

```html
{{hero}}
```

to

```html
<h2>{{hero.name}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div><span>name: </span>{{hero.name}}</div>
```

The above works for me, but originally I made a small deviation and had the template contents surrounded by a paragraph HTML element

like this:

```html
<p>{{hero}}</p>
```

The problem is that while the above used to work, when hero was a simple String object, changing the template to the following generates no output. I.e. inspecting the source I just see empty app-root element.

```html
<p>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} Details</h2>
    <div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div><span>name: </span>{{hero.name}}</div>
</p>
```

What could be wrong? UM, finally I found out the error, but am open to comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UM, OK, I am just posting this and keeping this for future reference. Nothing to do with Angular. Never realised that I was not allowed to do so..

There was an error in the javascript console that I was ignoring. It went like this:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected closing tag "p". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags

Searching for THAT I found out that Angular, and in fact the whole HTML specification doesn't like P tag with child elements that are not textual - as I understand it, it's a tag that should be used for immediate formatting, like B, and not for building a structure or a layout. There's an extensive discussion about this issue [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6648).